# Export a csv with product name and thumbnail image?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, importexport

I know it's possible to export csv's from Magento. Is there a way to get a small image to export in a column and not just the image path or url.

Also, I know _media_image is a field, is that an actual image file or no? Sorry for the naive question.

Or if this isn't possible is there any other way you think it could be done?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You want to download all images from csv ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't export the image in csv product export, only image `url` to the media file like thumbnail, base image are exported with the product export functionality.

To achieve this you need to download images from this path and put in your **CSV.**

You can refer below link for more light.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948063/magento-import-product-images-media-via-csv

Answer (score 0):

i need to export from Magento  a CSV file with the related image but i need the full link of the image like it is in the front end to import the file to WooCommerce.
i.e.: link of image is:https://www.khouryhome.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/900x900/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/4/i48046.jpg (i need like this link in each SKU)

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara NO not at all, same subject but wasn't able to make it, i need to export from Magento all SKU with the related images. the existing module import/export is showing i/8/image.png but i need the full URL can you help?